# How to Permanent Redirect a Directory That No Longer Exists (via .htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am having trouble redirecting an entire directory that no longer exists on our server.

All variations of the following are not working and I simply get a 404 Page Not Found.

**.htaccess file looks like this:**

```
redirect 301 /non_existent_directory/ http://my.website.com/existent_directory/
```

Is it possible to use the Redirect 301 directive for this? Or is this only solvable by mod_rewrite?

Thanks

**I even tried:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my\.website\.com\/non_existent_directory\/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my.website.com/existent_directory/ [R=301,L]
```

No luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) documentation, I would say

```
Redirect 301 /non_existent_directory http://my.website.com/existent_directory
```

or

```
Redirect 301 /non_existent_directory /existent_directory
```

should work, provided you are [allowed](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) to use this in a .htaccess file. See also [Troubleshooting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#troubleshoot) .htaccess files. You should test without `301` though, to prevent caching of bad redirects by the client.

If this doesn't work, you can try a `RewriteRule` of course

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?non_existent_directory(.*)$ /existent_directory$1 [R,L]
```

But this is equivalent to the above `Redirect` directive.

Comment: I am allowed to use .htaccess -- it is used prevalently across my entire server. Yet that directive results in a 404 PNF @OlafDietsche whenever I hit anything at `http://my.website.com/non_existent_directory` or `http://my.website.com/non_existent_directory/` or `http://my.website.com/non_existent_directory/anypage.html`

Comment: I have used other redirect 301's in other .htaccess files fpr missing files and they have worked. This is the first time I am trying to redirect an entire directory that no longer exists...

Comment: @H.Ferrence Without log information, it is difficult to tell what really happens. Anyway, you might try the other alternatives above.

Comment: Well, that is so bizarre...`Redirect 301 /non_existent_directory http://my.website.com/existent_directory` worked and all I did was capitalize the "r" in Redirect:) I am sure I somehow mis-typed something in my testing, but I was almost positive the answer you provided here did not work for me earlier. Nonetheless -- problem solved. Thanks @OlafDietsche